# SAPUI5 JSONModel cant be updated in controler

Tags: combobox, model, sapui5

i have 2 Comboboxes on my view.xml. If one changes his content, the other should apear.

```
<ComboBox id="cb1_ort_anla" width="100%" selectionChange="selChange" value="{/item/value1}" selectedKey="1">
..
</ComboBox>
<ComboBox id="cb2_oa" width="100%" selectionChange="onChange" value="{/item/value2}" selectedKey="1" visible="{/visibility_loc_sub}">
</ComboBox>
```

In the controler, i am defining a model with the properties from above:

```
onInit : function (){
        this.oModel = new JSONModel(
        {   "visibility_loc_sub" : false,
            "visibility_asset" : true,
            "item":{
                "value1":"",
                "value2":"",
                "value3":""
            }
        });
        this.getView().setModel(this.oModel);
    }
```

the methode selChange should change the property "visibility_loc_sub" to true with this code:

```
    selChange : function(oEvent){
        this.oModel.setProperty("visibility_loc_sub", true); 
        this.getView().setModel(this.oModel);
    } <--
```

In the debugger the property visibility_loc_sub at this(<--) point is still false. "this.oModel.visibility_loc_sub= true;" is not working either.

Am i doing something wrong? And if yes, what should i do?

thanks for your help!

Comment: You forgot the leading `/` when setting the property (it's absolute, not relative), i.e. `this.oModel.setProperty("/visibility_loc_sub", true);`

Comment: Should "this.oModel.visibility_loc_sub= true;" work too?

Comment: No, because `setProperty` also updates the control bindings

Comment: Also, you don't need to call `setModel(...)` again after setting the property